# How to build flyway java-based migrations

Tags: java, flyway

I'm using flyway command-line tool to handle my db migrations.
Till now all migrations are sql

Config file(only used options):

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://db.host
flyway.user=user
flyway.password=password

flyway.table=flyway_migrations

flyway.locations=filesystem:/home/........./sql/migrations

flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix=update
flyway.validateOnMigrate=false
flyway.outOfOrder=true
```

That works perfectly.

But for now I need to add one java-based migration. And I'm really puzzled
I can't find any How todo examples. How to compile, where to put java migrations.

I've tried simple migration-class from official documentation:

```
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Example of a Java-based migration.
 */
public class V50_121_1__update_notes implements JdbcMigration {
    public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement statement =
            connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test_user (name) VALUES ('Obelix')");

        try {
            statement.execute();
        } finally {
            statement.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But what to do next? 
Tried compiling:

```
javac -cp "./flyway-core-3.2.1.jar" V50_121_1__update_notes.java
jar cf V50_121_1__update_dataNode_notes.jar V50_121_1__update_dataNode_notes.class
```

And then putting that jar to different locations, have no effect.

flyway info - don't see the migration.

So how to build the simplest java-based migration. I will prefer not to use Maven, or something similar. Just simple jar file(???) which is picked up by flyway command-line tool.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `.class` file is in a `db/migration` directory inside your `.jar` file file and that your `.jar` file is placed in the `/jars` directory of your Flyway installations.

`flyway.locations` should also be set to:

```
db.migration,filesystem:/home/........./sql/migrations
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding db.migration to locations, that is what I missed

Comment: @Vadym Kovalenko am also facing similar issue , would you be able to help me Please. I have added the db/migration into flyway.locations and the jar file is placed inside jar folders But still am facing the same error " Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration" , Please let me know if you need any other details

Comment: @AdarshHDDev Does sql and/or class files inside jar file located inside classpath  - db/migration ?

Comment: @VadymKovalenko yes the class file inside the jar file is located in the db/migration. Am using the same java class file which is mentioned in your question. I don't have any sql inside the classpath db/migration the jar file only contains the .class file, inside the classpath. Here is the link to my question over stackover flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571632/unable-to-scan-for-sql-migrations-in-location-classpathdb-migration  it contains step by step details of what am trying to do. Could you please help thanks.

Comment: @VadymKovalenko I am facing error like WARNING: Unable to resolve location classpath:db/migration. have you followed other steps a part from mentioned details here

Comment: @Axel Fontaine could you explain how flyway migration process works? it monitors the .class files in the file system when a new one appears it executes the JDBC command in the class file or ....

Answer (score 1):

Specify for `.java` files as `.java` como

**classpath**: `package_example.migrations`

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://db.host
flyway.user=user
flyway.password=password

flyway.table=flyway_migrations

flyway.locations=filesystem:/home/...../sql/migrations,classpath:pack_example.migrations

flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix=update
flyway.validateOnMigrate=false
flyway.outOfOrder=true
```

See the link for documentation
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate