# Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration

Tags: java, deployment, flyway

I am using flyway to do the SQL migration , the sql migration worked for me perfectly .

Now am trying to do the simple java migration using Flyway, below is the code which am using

```
package db.migration;

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Example of a Java-based migration.
 */
public class V2__Test implements JdbcMigration {
public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement statement =
        connection.prepareStatement("create table test (id int)");

    try {
        statement.execute();
    } finally {
        statement.close();
    }
}
}
```

I created a Jar file out of this class file and placed the Jar file under Flyway_home/Jars folder. Later I mentioned the db/migration in the config file as below

```
flyway.locations=db.migration
```

After this am running the migrate command from cmd utility as below

```
flyway  -configFile=conf/flyway-fte-Data.conf migrate
```

am getting the below error

```
ERROR: Unable to scan for SQL migrations in location: classpath:db/migration
```

What am missing here, could anyone please help me to fix this.

Note:  I am not using any plugin, its just flyway command line Utility.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2020 and the problem remains, I just gave up writing java-based migration. It worked running flyway as a plugin, but when I use the image and tried to map to flyway/jars volume and setting the location, it throws me warnings about could not find location.

Answer (score 1):

The property 'flyway.locations' configures the location of the SQL migration files and you want to run the java migration files. So I think it's enough when you comment out this property in your configuarion, because the Flyway_home/jars folder is the default value for the java migration location property ('flyway.jarDirs'). The next possibility is to set this property ('flyway.jarDirs') to your favour jar location.

Comment: @SandrParsick , I tired commenting the "flyway.locations" but then it says that  there is no migration required its not even identifying the Jar file i think   
   " Database: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localHost/test (Microsoft SQL Server 11.0)
    Validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.359s)
    Current version of schema [dbo]: 1
    Schema [dbo] is up to date. No migration necessary."           The current java file name i have mentioned version as 2 and the baseline version  is 1 so ideally it should try to migrate the file which is not happening.

Comment: Call 'flyway info' to check whether your java migration script is noticed by flyway

Comment: @SandraPasrick,  i tired the "flyway info" , but that is showing me only the baseline version my Jar file is not being detected, am i missing something , is there something i need change ?

Comment: Here my [Maven pom setting](https://github.com/sparsick/flyway-talk/tree/master/flyway-demo/database-scripts) to build the jar file with flyway java migration files and here my [flyway.conf](https://github.com/sparsick/flyway-talk/tree/master/flyway-3.2.1/conf). Maybe it helps when you compare your setting with my setting.

Comment: Thanks for the details , but i don't want to use any Pulgin's am just trying the normal Flyway from command line. I believe that Pom setting is used when we are using Maven Pulgin right.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. That example should only shows the structure of my jar. I checked agaiin the default value for jar folder and it flyway_home/jars with a small j. The next possibilty is to set the property 'flyway.jarDirs' to your favourite location for your jar.

Comment: I tried explictly mentioning the Jar's director path in config but still is the same :(

Comment: @AdarshHDDev I am facing same issue. do you found solution?

Comment: @TTT Nope i couldn't find solution do this its still remains open thing with me.

Comment: ohk. is there any option that way you can achieve command line flyway migration with java